# How to use FLEX in CMAKE

Tags: c, cmake, lex, flex-lexer

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong when trying to use just flex in a Cmake file to build a shared lib.

i basically have the following

```
find_package(FLEX)
FLEX_TARGET(Test ../src/test.l ../src/test.c)
set(SRC_FILES mysource.c ${FLEX_Test_OUTPUTS})
add_libary(testlib ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(testlib crypto c ${FLEX_LIBRARIES})
```

this is giving me a problem saying it cant find ../src/test.c

any ideas how I can make sure Lex ran first? secondly,how can i pass my -L and -d options to lex (like I am doing in my normal, pre-cmake version of this makefile)

Comment: I Retagged this; as I Believe it is a question about the Lexical Analyzer (AKA Lex or gnu-flex) and not about the UI Framework (Adobe/Apache Flex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want output file to be in the source dir?

I'd recommend using `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`:

```
FLEX_TARGET(Test ../src/test.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../src/test.c)
```

As for

> any ideas how I can make sure Lex ran first?

you don't need to do it, CMake can guess this dependency by it's own. I think the problem is either in using source dir for output file, or the `../src` dir doesn't exist before `flex` runs.

> secondly,how can i pass my -L and -d options to lex

List them after the output parameter:

```
FLEX_TARGET(Test ../src/test.l ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../src/test.c -L -d)
```